# MFC: CToolTipCtrl::SetTipBkColor not working

Tags: mfc, tooltip

I am trying to customize my tooltips with dark background so that they are clearly visbile. I have tried using the CToolTipCtrl::SetTipBkColor for that purpose. But I am still seeing the default style tooltip with silver gradient background with dropshadow.

Please find the sample code I have used for this purpose.

```
BOOL CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
m_ToolTipCtrl.Create(this, TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_NOPREFIX );
m_ToolTipCtrl.Activate(TRUE);
m_ToolTipCtrl.SetDelayTime(TTDT_INITIAL, 0);
m_ToolTipCtrl.SetTipBkColor(RGB(255,0,0));

CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1);
m_ToolTipCtrl.AddTool(pWnd,_T("TOOLTIP Displayed"));

return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
// EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Upon searching I have found that I need to disable visual styles. I don't know what it really means. I am thinking it has something to do with CToolTipCtrl:::SetWindowTheme but have no clue of what value needs to be passed.

Comment: When I switch my windows theme to "Windows classic" I can see old style tooltips and I can change the background color too. Can we somehow change the theme of this particular Tooltip to classic?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass a blank string for the theme:

```
m_ToolTipCtrl.SetWindowTheme("");
```

Comment: SetWindowTheme expects LPCWSTR. so tried this        m_ToolTipCtrl.SetWindowTheme(_T(""));  but this is not working.

Comment: @Aditya: How is it not working? What error are you getting? Compile error? Run-time error? I just used `m_ToolTipCtrl.SetWindowTheme(_T(""));` with no problems.

Comment: with `m_ToolTipCtrl.SetWindowTheme(_T(""));` it compiles and runs fine but I can't see any change in the behavior